# WPF - binding to a property of a custom object that is inside another object

Tags: c#, xaml, c#-4.0, binding

I'm working in WPF 4 / C#. I have two custom classes:

```
public class c1 {
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    public c1() {
        prop1 = "world";
    }
}

public class c2 {
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public c1 obj1 = new c1();

    public c2() {
        prop1 = "hello";
    }
}
```

From within XAML, I want to bind to properties of these classes. Here is what I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:c2 x:Key="c2"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock DataContext="{DynamicResource c2}" Text="{Binding prop1}"/>
    <TextBlock DataContext="{DynamicResource c2}" Text="{Binding obj1.prop1}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

(Here the `<my:c2 ../>` instantiates the c2 class.) The first TextBlock binding works. The second does not. Why can't I bind to a property on the obj1? I only seem to be able to bind to properties of the immediate class. I want to be able to bind to other stuff like an element in an array that belongs to the immediate class or a property of a child class, as shown above. What am I missing? If I wrap the obj1.prop1 in another property of the immediate class using get/set, it works. But I don't want to have to do that, particularly if I start using arrays, I don't want to wrap each element into a separate property!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `obj1` is a field, not a property, therefore you can't access the C1 object.

Consider this instead:

```
public class c2 {
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    private readonly c1 _obj1;

    public c2() {
        prop1 = "hello";
        _obj1 = new c1();
    }

    public c1 PropObj1 { get { return _obj1; } }
}
```

And

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{DynamicResource c2}" Text="{Binding PropObj1.prop1}"/>
```

PS. Next time better to use an example with standard naming conventions (e.g. lower case fields/variables, upper case properties etc) to allow people to see the problem sooner!

Answer (score 10):

You can't bind to fields, they have to be properties.

Comment: I AM trying to bind to a property, it just happens to be on a child object. Is the problem occurring because the child object is a field and there is no way to "bind past" it to get to the property?

Comment: @mawrya the child object itself also needs to be a property, i.e. `prop1` is a property on `obj1`, but `obj1` itself is not a property of your `c2` class.