# How to use foreign keyed column to fetch data from a column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, linq-to-sql

I have this data grid sourced to a observablecollection Order based on tbl_Order. Now in tbl_Order I have a foreign key column ProdID that is the primary key of tbl_Product. Now the datagridcolumn is binded to ProdID column but what I want is actually the ProdName to be displayed in that column for viewing purpose . I am using linq to SQL for querying so in my Order collection I have this property

```
Order. tbl_Product.Prod_Name
```

How can I use the above mentioned statement in linq to fetch data n how should I bind it to the column like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="Order.tbl_Product.ProdName">
```

This doesn't work in xaml

Plz help me around this.Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to fields, they have to be properties !

Please refer to the following solution :

[WPF - binding to a property of a custom object that is inside another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456249/wpf-binding-to-a-property-of-a-custom-object-that-is-inside-another-object)

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Use **Include** keywork in linq to sql query and get tbl_Product information

And to bind the column to Datagrid following code can be used

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="Order.tbl_Product.ProdName">
```